# MariaDB ColumnStore Bulk Write SDK takes forever

Tags: java, mariadb, columnstore

I am trying to use MariaDB ColumnStore Bulk Write SDK in Java to bulk insert 10 rows in a table with 50 columns(data type int) but it never finished had to kill the process in 10 -15 tried couple times but same results.

this is the code sample from their doc 
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/columnstore-bulk-write-sdk/#rhel-centos-7

```
import com.mariadb.columnstore.api.*;

public class MCSAPITest {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
        ColumnStoreDriver d = new ColumnStoreDriver();
        ColumnStoreBulkInsert b = d.createBulkInsert("test", "t1", (short)0, 0);
        try {
           int rows = 10;
           int columns = 50;
           for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
            for (int c = 0; c < columns; ++c) {
                b.setColumn(c, 0);
            }
            System.out.println("Writing row: " + i);
            b.writeRow();
        }
        System.out.println("Commiting Now");
        b.commit();
        }
        catch (ColumnStoreException e) {
            b.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Tried reducing the columns to 20 and works ok. 
Has anyone noticed this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've raised to the dev team and the issue is fixed in 1.1.4 version.More details are here. https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MCOL-1245

Answer (score 0):

If you followed the tutorial and created the table as:

```
create table t1(i int, c char(3)) engine=columnstore;
```

You can only insert data into two columns. Double-checking that the number of columns in the table matches the number of columns you are inserting would be wise.

Regardless of how many columns are in the table, inserting more columns than are in the table should raise an exception. The usual recommendation is to open a bug report for this unexpected behavior on [the MariaDB Jira under the ColumnStore project](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MCOL).

Running the code under a debugger would allow you to spot where the code appears to hang. This is valuable information that the developers can use to figure out why it is not behaving as expected.

Comment: The table is created with 50 columns with int datatype.